# wordpress admin dashboard redirects to This page could not be found

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-404

I tried removing .htaccess file,change in config,check site url,clear cache cookies, renaming plugins folder, theme folder, but it didnt works and redirect to 404 page [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJx4d.png) wp admin look like this in image and click on anything on wp-admin redirect to page not found

Comment: Could you show your inspector and network tab to see what is exactly failing? If you could provide your sever error log that would be great.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem a few times.

First of all, try saving the permalinks, if you can't access it screen just delete the .htaccess.

These errors happened to me a few times and the problem was generally:

1 - My internet connection and the hosting server were conflicting but on another pc it worked so I changed the internet connection (In my case I have two internet providers) and it worked normally. I called the internet provider and they settled, but it did a great job making them understand rsrsrsrs.

2 - Some temporary instability with your hosting contact them to check.

3 - Some plugin option has broken your site, but in your case it should not be that since it has done the necessary tests to verify it.

4 - Have some malware try re-installing a new wp subfolder to test if the problem persists, then contact the hosting. but if it works normally then it should be some malwer try re-installing wordpress to fix it and install security plugins

First of all test on another pc to see if the problem continues but test on another pc that doesn't use the same internet provider as you.

If the error persists please update the question with more information to help you. like network data, plugins, themes etc that you are using